# Rails Devise Rolify collection of employee with a role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Devise and Rolify.

Employee `belongs_to User` and User `has_one :employee`.
The User model has `rolify`.

Because of Rolify, there is a table called `user_roles`.

The following code works fine:

```
<% if current_user.has_role? :super %>
```

And this would work if I wanted to associate with the user instead of the employee:

```
:collection => User.with_role(:agent)
```

Now, I would like to have an association in a form that contains a select for employees that have a role of "agent".

The following tries don't work:

```
<%= f.association :employee, :collection => Employee.user.with_role(:agent), :label_method => :employee_full_name, :label => 'Agent' %>
```

The one above gives this error:

```
undefined method `user' for #<Class:0x007fac48215ee8>
```

This doesn't work either:

```
<%= f.association :employee, :collection => User.with_role(:agent).employee.id, :label_method => :employee_full_name, :label => 'Agent' %>
```

What would work?

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

The following works to display a list of employees with their associated role:

```
<td><%= employee.user.roles.first.name %></td>
```

UPDATE2

Because `employee.user.roles.first.name` will give me the role name for an employee, I tried this:

```
Employee.where('employee.user.roles.first.name = ?', 'agent')
```

But, I get a PG error =

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  improper qualified name (too many dotted names): employee.user.roles.first.name
```

Comment: What is your association between users and roles?

Comment: The User model has `rolify`. The rolify gem provides a one user to many roles via the users_roles table.  I don't have a statement in the User model concerning roles.  Maybe that's the problem - I'll try adding one. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes.

Employee.joins(:user).where(:employees => { :user_id => User.with_role(:agent) })

Comment: Polmiro, I really appreciate your help and I'm willing to accept this answer.  But, should you or j03w get credit?  I changed one word in his suggestion.

Comment: I appreciate your help! You were definitely on the right track. j03w had a slightly different answer - but, with a similar thought process.  I accepted your answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

`Employee.user.with_role(:agent)`

Brings back all Employees with the agent role. The problem with your first 2 is that you are calling `has_role` on `Employee` which had not been 'rolified'.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm trying to find Employees with role 'agent'.  The Employee has a one-to-one with user.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an instance method 'user' to a class Employee. As you said, if Employee belongs to user you will want to make a join there (I am assuming you have the relation has_one :employee in the User model):

```
Employee.joins(:user => :user_roles).merge(User.with_role(:agent))
```

Or

```
Employee.joins(:user => { :user_roles => :roles}).merge(User.with_role(:agent))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  But, if I use your first example for the collection, I get undefined method `employee_full_name'.  I'm using user belongs_to :employee and user has_one :employee.

Comment: If I use your alternative, I get `Association named 'roles' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: I added a comment on top. There is a different problem now. Method employee_full_name does not exist in Employee. You might want to define it or rename de method.

Comment: employee.rb has ` def employee_full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
` - but, even if I use `last_name` which is a field in the Employee table, I get the same results.  With your first answer it's looking to display a field from User not Employee.  I want the association with Employee.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is closer to what I need - but, doesn't quite work `<%= f.association :employee, :collection => Employee.joins(:user).merge(User.with_role(:agent)), :label_method => :last_name, :label => 'Assigned To' %>`

Comment: You're right, if it's a method of Employee we should retrieve Employee instances. I updated the answer again. That should get you going.

Comment: With the new stmt I get `undefined local variable or method `roles' for #<#<Class:0x007f919c008f40>:0x007f919b77d9c0>`

Comment: I don't know if it's significant. But, there is a table called users_roles.

Comment: Polmiro - I don't see a correction.  The current one give me `Association named 'roles' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: You would be better of showing exactly what your models and schema look like next time. I added two alternatives, not sure which one applies to you.

Comment: try `Employee.joins(:user => :user_roles).where(:user_roles => { :name => 'agent'})` Or `Employee.joins(:user).where(:user => { :user_id => User.with_role(:agent) })`

Comment: j03w - your second one created this SQL: `SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "employees"."user_id" WHERE "employees"."tenant_id" = 1 
AND "user"."user_id" IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "users_roles"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users"."tenant_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'agent') 
` that gave me error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"
LINE 1: ..."."user_id" WHERE "employees"."tenant_id" = 1 AND "user"."us...`

Comment: j03w - I made a slight change to your 2nd suggestion and it works!! `Employee.joins(:user).where(:employees => { :user_id => User.with_role(:agent) })`  Provide answer and I'll accept it.